# Table Data Import! Can't analyze file. Please try to change encoding type. ERROR MySQL8.0.20

Tags: mysql

I am trying to import a CSV file to MySQL table using 'Table Data Import Wizard', but after choose the file MySQL Workbench returns:

> 'Table Data Import! Can't analyze file. Please try to change encoding type.'

My file was created from Python dataframe and received 'encoding=utf-8'.
OBS: I have 5 more tables that are imported perfectly.

**Code:**

```
create table circuito(
ID_CIRCUITO smallint not null,
NOME_CIRCUITO varchar(100) not null,
EXTENSÃO decimal(5,3),
ID_PAIS char(3) not null,
primary key(ID_CIRCUITO),
constraint FK_pais_circuito foreign key (ID_PAIS) references pais(ID_PAIS)
)default charset = utf8 engine=InnoDB;
```

Comment: How does that CSV file look like? What have you tried to spot the problem?

Comment: Follow the head of csv file, with 4 columns.

Circuito_ID,Circuito_Nome,Extensão_KM,Pais_ID
1,Albert Park Grand Prix Circuit,5.303,AUS
2,Sepang International Circuit,5.343,MAL
3,Bahrain International Circuit,5.412,BAH